# Consuming salesforce Rest API with out security token

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, apexrest, rest-service

I am exposing a API in salesforce which will be hit by an external c# application. I am enabled oAuth mechanism. Things are looking good but when the external end point needs to pass user id  and password + security token to get the access token. Is there any other way to get the access token as because password will get changed every three month for my user id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by using one of the other [OAuth 2.0 flows](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_flows.htm&type=5) that Salesforce supports.

It sounds like you're using the Username-Password flow (which is mostly only suitable for testing/prototyping). If you are unable to show a screen to a user (for them to enter their own credentials), then the only other non-interactive flow is the JWT Bearer flow.